# merge the sum of 3 columns into another column in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, currency

I want to merge the **sum** of 3 columns (price_crore,price_lakh,price_thousand) in mysql table into another column called '**amount**'.

For example
price_crore,price_lakh,price_thousand for which values are as follows 1,75,50. on the **amount** column I want the result **17550000**

note: according to indian currency system: price_crore= 10,000,000 (1 crore) and price_lakh=100000 (1 lakh) and price_thousand=1000(1 thousand).

please help me achive the above result in **php**.

Comment: OK, well first of all you're not looking for the sum, you're looking to concatenate.  Which may help in your searching.  Beyond that, feel free to show what you've attempted so far, there are any number of viable methods to do this, but choosing the most appropriate one depends on what's going on in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to do the math:

```
select   price_crore
       , price_lakh
       , price_thousand
       ,   (price_crore    * 10000000)
         + (price_lakh     *   100000)
         + (price_thousand *     1000) as amount
from some_table
```

Answer (score 1):

use [concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function , something like :

```
select concat(sum(price_crore),sum(price_lakh),sum(price_thousand)) .. 
from mytable group by ...
```

Comment: thanks for the help, based on your answer it just outputs 17550